# AWS Timestream: Given correlated subquery is not supported

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, time-series, amazon-timestream

```
select host, time as currentTime, floor((1 - (
  select sum(measure_value::double)
    from "DendroTimestreamDB"."hostMetrics"
    where cpuMode = 'idle'
    and time <= h.time
    group by host
) / ((
  select sum(measure_value::double)
    from "DendroTimestreamDB"."hostMetrics"
    where cpuMode = 'idle'
    and time <= h.time
    group by host
) + (
  select sum(measure_value::double)
    from "DendroTimestreamDB"."hostMetrics"
    where cpuMode = 'system'
    and time <= h.time
    group by host
) + (
  select sum(measure_value::double)
    from "DendroTimestreamDB"."hostMetrics"
    where cpuMode = 'user'
    and time <= h.time
    group by host
))) * 100) as utilization
from "DendroTimestreamDB"."hostMetrics" h
group by host, time
```

returns the error `line 20:3: Given correlated subquery is not supported` but according to [Timestream subquery support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/supported-sql-constructs.subquery-support.html)

> The Timestream query language supports correlated and other subqueries.

Columns:

> cpuMode,
> host,
> device,
> cpuCode,
> collector,
> measure_value::double,
> measure_name,
> time,

Sample data:

> idle,  MacBook-Pro.local,  -,  0,  cpu,    115950.13,  cpu_seconds_total, 2021-04-29 13:46:11.000000000

Desired Output:

> host,
> time,
> utilization

> MacBook-Pro.local 2021-04-29 13:47:56.000000000   15

> MacBook-Pro.local 2021-04-29 13:47:41.000000000   16

> MacBook-Pro.local 2021-04-29 13:47:26.000000000   19

I'm trying to calculate CPU utilization using the formula (1 - idleTime / totalTime) * 100 but apparently, these correlated subqueries aren't supported. Do I just have to rewrite it in a different way?

In the summation subqueries I'm trying to calculate the sum of the measure values that were received previous to the time from the main query and I'm doing this using the lines `and time <= h.time` causing the queries to be correlated and thus the issue.

Thanks a ton

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want conditional aggregation.  I can't really follow the logic, but the components would appear to be something like this:

```
select host, time as currentTime,
       sum(sum(case when cpuMode = 'idle' then measure_value::double)) over (partition by host order by time)
       sum(sum(case when cpuMode = 'system' then measure_value::double)) over (partition by host order by time)
       sum(sum(case when cpuMode = 'user' then measure_value::double)) over (partition by host order by time)
from "DendroTimestreamDB"."hostMetrics" h
group by host, time
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed! thank you